# I can't set String[] value in my spinner

Tags: java, android, string, spinner

I'm newbie in android programmer.I have problem that I can't to show `AirNum[]` in my spinner.

```
            String AirNum[]=new String[10];
            int i;

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
            ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            String Url = "...url for viewsorce...";

            Document doc = null;
            try
           {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(Url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements flightnum = doc.select("p.flightNum");
            for(i=0;i<flightnum.size();i++)
            { AirNum[i] = flightnum.get(i).text();}

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,AirNum);
            sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this my logcat

```
04-24 00:09:44.638: E/AndroidRuntime(9619): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 00:09:44.638: E/AndroidRuntime(9619): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
04-24 00:09:44.638: E/AndroidRuntime(9619): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-24 00:09:44.638: E/AndroidRuntime(9619): at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:681)
```

Comment: getView of adapter returns null. it should return a view

Comment: I use textview for show data.textview can show value but spinner can't show this value

Comment: `flightnum` may be null. put `if(flightnum!=null)` before looping.

Comment: @TBM I put if same you.It's error same above.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You create a String[]

```
new String[10];
```

Latter, you populate it with `flightnum.size()` elements. In there is not exactly 10 elements here, it will crash (here if there are more than 10 elements, in the setAdapter if there are less).

Use a List instead:

```
List<String> AirNum = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And replace:

```
AirNum[i] = flightnum.get(i).text();
```

by

```
AirNum.add(flightnum.get(i).text());
```

Comment: or do String [] AirNum = new String[flightnum.size()]; However, my personal preference is always to use Lists as you have pointed out.

Comment: @confused_at_times: yes, that would work, except apparently the String[] is created as an instance member, and therefore flightnum.size() is probably not available at that point. There is always the possibility to move the definition, but that may have side effects if AirNum is referenced somewhere else.

Comment: @njzk2 I try to change same you. I replace String AirNum[]=new String[10]; by List<String> AirNum = new ArrayList<String>(); and AirNum[i] = flightnum.get(i).text(); by AirNum.add(flightnum.get(i).text()); and change adapter by  List<String> adapter = new ArrayList<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,AirNum); //It's error this adapter

Comment: @user3565634: what? don't change the adapter! when did i ever mentioned anything about changing the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Android 4.2 right? In Android 4.2's source code, at ArrayAdapter.java:394, there is

```
text.setText(item.toString());
```

So either `text` is null, or `item` is null.

Because you supplied an Android system resource id to ArrayAdapter, `text` is unlikely to be null. So you'd better check whether your `item` can be null.

You initialized your list items from `flightnum.get(i).text()`. Better check whether that can return null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is because Android can't link to a layout element properly. I think this is why it is having a problem with the measurement width. You haven't defined what sp1 is (please do so), but the code below is generally how you take a spinner defined in xml (you can just use one created programmatically instead), defines and populates your String array, creates the ArrayAdapter and then ties it to the Spinner object.

Hopefully this helps.

Edit: I made the first letter of the String array lower-case to conform to standard naming conventions. Generally, you should only capitalise the first letter of classes. Methods and variables should have a lower-case first letter. There may be exceptions to this that I'm not aware of or rarely ever use.

### Code snippet:

```
Spinner spinner = ((Spinner) currDialog.findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id));

if (spinner == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Spinner is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {

    String [] airNum = new String [10];

    //
    //populate string
    //
    //

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, airNum);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```